# GPUImage: strange image deformation (but only with some photo)

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm trying to implement some Camera filter in my app, using [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). Everything works fine, but sometime, with some (a few, really) photo i get the following result:

[image]

I'm using GPUImageLookupFilter, here is the code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource;

----

_stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:self.previewImage]; <- in viewDidLoad

----

[_stillImageSource removeAllTargets];
GPUImagePicture *lookUpSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.lookUpArray[sender.tag]]];
GPUImageLookupFilter *lookUpFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
[_stillImageSource addTarget:lookUpFilter];
[lookUpSource addTarget:lookUpFilter];
[_stillImageSource processImage];
[lookUpSource processImage];
self.imageView.image = [lookUpFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

Anyone has an idea?

PS: sorry for my english.

EDIT:

**Here is the solution**: [ios GPUImage,bad result of image processing with small-size images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097560/ios-gpuimage-bad-result-of-image-processing-with-small-size-images)

Comment: Do the images where this problem happens have an odd width by any chance? I sometimes see this sort of problem when I have an off-by-one error in my images, which usually only happens when they're an odd width.

Comment: No, one of this is 498.000000x976.000000 and another is 538.000000x720.000000. No odd width at all.

Comment: Finally i found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097560/ios-gpuimage-bad-result-of-image-processing-with-small-size-images